# IntelliJ not recognizing typescript named module declarations

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I have a situation where my module names need to be in a certain format.  Typescript is fine when I do this:

```typescript
// knockout interfaces, this is knockout.d.ts
declare var ko: KnockoutStatic;
declare module "core!lib/knockout" {
    export = ko;
}
```

And then in my file that uses it:

```typescript
import ko = require('core!lib/knockout');
```

IntelliJ doesn't like it though.  It says "cannot find external module 'core!lib/knockout'. I'm using the latest stable version (14.1) and this happens with the in-built 1.4 compiler and a custom one.

I guess this may be a Jetbrains bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to the file with the import statement the error will probably go away

```
/// <reference path="test.ts" />
```

The real problem I think is that the configuration isn't fully correct. Is the config root correct or are you maybe using version control?

Relevant bits from the link:

```
From the Scope drop-down list, choose the scope to apply the compiler in. The available options are: – Project Files: all the files within the project content roots (see Content Root and Configuring Content Roots). 
– Project Production Files: all the files within the project content roots excluding test sources. 
– Project Test Files: all the files within the project test source roots. 
– Open Files: all the files that are currently opened in the editor. 

VCS Scopes: these scopes are only available if your project is under version control. 
– Changed Files: all changed files, that is, all files associated with all existing changelists. 
– Default: all the files associated with the changelist
```

See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/transpiling-typescript-to-javascript.html

Comment: Ah.  My scope was okay.  I'm using grunt-ts, and since the editor has been happily giving me intellisense without having to ///reference my references.ts I thought I didn't have to include it.  Doing so makes the errors go away.